# Meaning of “emphasis” in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context

> It is as if the “I know” does not go well with a metaphysical emphasis (Ludwig Wittgenstein, *On Certainty*)

In this context, what is the meaning of the word “emphasis?”

Comment: Can't emphasis just mean stress or extra focus?

Comment: It causes you to place the emphAHsis on the wrong syllAHble.

Comment: There is nothing in this sentence that needs an explanation so far as the language is concerned. This is a question that calls for a substantive explanation a philosophical text, which is outside the topic of this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Lexico:

> **[emphasis](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/emphasis)**: Special importance, value, or prominence given to something.

> **[metaphysical](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/metaphysical)**: Relating to metaphysics.

> **[metaphysics](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/metaphysics)**: The branch of philosophy that deals with the first principles of things, including abstract concepts such as being, knowing, substance, cause, identity, time, and space.

> > Metaphysics has two main strands: that which holds that what exists lies beyond experience (as argued by Plato), and ***that which holds that objects of experience constitute the only reality (as argued by Kant, the logical positivists, and Hume)***. Metaphysics has also concerned itself with a discussion of whether what exists is made of one substance or many, and whether what exists is inevitable or driven by chance [emphasis mine]

Wittgenstein turned to [logical positivism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludwig_Wittgenstein) in the 1920s, long before he created the content that came to compose *[On Certainty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_Certainty)*, which is why I've used the definition of *metaphysics* cited above.

What the sentence you've quoted is saying is that if you try to add "special importance, value, or prominence" to the metaphysical aspects of "I know," it will not work well because "I know" flies in the face of the above definition of metaphysics, "which holds that objects of experience constitute the only reality."